# Create a Firebase Dynamic Link for an app without adding it to the project

Tags: android, ios, firebase, deep-linking, firebase-dynamic-links

I need to create dynamic links to multiple different apps (different package names or in case of iOS, bundle IDs).
Firebase need the apps to be added to the project before letting me to create a dynamic link for them.

How can I redirect the user to the apps which are not added to Firebase project?

Comment: Sina, you have to add App to Firebase Console to use Firebase Dynamic Links for the App.

One of the reasons for this:
bundle ID and AppPrefix ID is required in order to use Universal Links.

Comment: @OleksiyIvanov, yes, you are right. But what is the situation with Android?

Comment: Do not have implementation details about Android. In Firebase it is similar, you have to add Apps to Firebase Console to use FDL for these Apps.

Is there specific reason why you don't want to add Apps? You have too many of them? Creating App in Firebase is relatively easy action. Feel free to reach out to me at oleksiyi _at_ google.com .

Comment: @OleksiyIvanov, yes I have too many of them. Adding them on Android is not that hard, thanks to Android Studio Firebase tool, but on iOS it's gonna take forever to add all of them.

Comment: Note for Android the requirements are similar - you need the SHA256 and the package name for the digital assets file. Right now there isn't a better supported route for creating a number of apps than doing them manually, sorry!